# Rails routing without resource name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

My rails app has a Section model and a Page model.  A section has many pages.

```
# section.rb
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :pages 
end

# page.rb
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :section 
end
```

Assuming I have a Section with slug 'about', and that section has three pages with slugs 'intro', 'people', 'history,' a url with typical routing might look something like this:

```
http://example.com/sections/about/pages/intro
http://example.com/sections/about/pages/people
http://example.com/sections/about/pages/history
```

What is the best way to set up my routes so that I can use these urls:

```
http://example.com/about/intro
http://example.com/about/people
http://example.com/about/history
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to remove "sections" and "pages" from all routes for both `sections` and `pages`, you could use:

```
resources :sections, path: '' do
  resources :pages, path: ''
end
```

**Important: be sure to put this to the bottom of your routes page.** For instance, it you have an `example` controller, and say your `routes.rb` appeared as follows:

```
resources :sections, path: '' do
  resources :pages, path: ''
end
resources :examples
root 'home#index'
```

With the above setup, going to `http://example.com/examples` would send you to the "examples" `section`, rather than than `examples#index`, and going to `http://example.com/` would send you to `sections#index` rather than `home#index`. So, the above configuration should look like this:

```
resources :examples
root 'home#index'
resources :sections, path: '' do
  resources :pages, path: ''
end
```

Comment: Thanks!  Exactly what I was looking for.  One note: 'resource' in your answer should be 'resources'?

Comment: No problem! And yes you're totally right, it should be `resources`, so I made the change.