# Ruby Rails - Routing without Resource Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url-routing

I'm currently using `friendly_id` and I'm trying to get route to not include the resource name.

Normally, the URL is `www.website.com/projects/25`.

With `friendly_id` it's `www.website.com/projects/fun-project`. This is what I currently have.

And I'd finally like it to be `www.website.com/fun-project`.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23459705/3106174) about this but the solution wasn't working for me for one case.

```
//routes.rb
root 'static#index'
...
resources :projects, path: ''
```

When doing `resources :projects, path: ''`, the `projects#show` works correctly, but I cannot use `projects#index` as I was before.

In my navigation, the `projects_path` that used to link to `www.website.com/projects` now just links to `www.website.com`.

Do I need to do something else for this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply `get` for this purpose in the following way:

```
get '/:project_id' => 'projects#show'
```

Comment: I have it mapping the `title` to `projects#show`, but the problem is removing the path because of `projects#index`.

Comment: Have `resources :projects, except: [:show]` at the top of `get '/:project_id' => 'projects#show'`, and it work for both: the index page, and the show page.

Comment: @Advice-Dog You may need to have a similar thing for the edit page of projects.

Comment: I've added `resources :projects, except: [:show]` at the top, and at the bottom `resources :projects, path: '', only: [:show]`, and this nearly works. `/projects` goes to `projects#index`, and `/fun-project` goes to the project. But the URL that's generated through `link_to` still says the full `/projects/fun-project`.

Comment: `<%= link_to project do %>` to wrap an `image_tag`.

Comment: Try: `<%= link_to "/#{project.name}" do %>`. Replace name with whatever column you are using for friendly-id.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand so far, you want the following URL to your projects resources.

`www.website.com/fun-project`

here 'fun-project' is the friendly id of your project.

In order to achieve this you can add the following line to your route:

`get '/:id' => 'projects#show'`

And should work!

Comment: I have it mapping the `title` to `projects#show`, but the problem is removing the path because of `projects#index`.

Comment: I think I got your point. But having:
`resources :projects, path: ''`
is not a good idea.

Comment: I get what you mean. I tried doing what you're suggesting, but for some reason my routes' `link_to` for the project generates the url to `/projects/:id`, which on clicking throws an error, but manually typing in `/:id` works fine.   --- I'm doing `resources :projects, except: [:show]` then `get '/:id' => 'projects#show'`